# Uniqueness of affine approximation?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined on $X\subset \mathbb R$ and let $a\in X\cap X^\prime$, where $X^\prime$ is the set of acummulation points of $X$. Let us say an affine function $\phi: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an **affine approximation of $f$ at $a$** if

$$\forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0; x\in X, |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-\phi(x)|<\varepsilon.$$

I'd like to show that if $\phi$ exists, then it is unique.

I thought of the following: Suppose $\phi_1, \phi_2: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are affine approximations of $f$ at $a$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ there are $\delta_1, \delta_2>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
x\in X, |x-a|<\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}\implies |\phi_1(x)-\phi_2(x)|&\leq |f(x)-\phi_1(x)|+|f(x)-\phi_2(x)|\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
&=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Is it enought to conclude that $\phi_1=\phi_2$? My intuition says so, but it feels like there is something missing in order to complete the argument.

Thanks.

Comment: Your condition is just $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)-\phi(x)) = 0$. That does not guarantee uniqueness. Also that is not what I know as “affine/linear approximation.” Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation

Comment: You're right, now I see my definition is not correct. However, with the correct definition, it must follow $\phi$ exists if and only if $$f^\prime(a)=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ exists and, in this case, $\phi(x)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(x-a)$.

Comment: Maybe I should require $\phi$ to satisfy  $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-\phi(x)}{x-a}=0?$$